# Any way to populate database by multiplying existing data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Rails app running on my localhost with about 10 posts including pictures. Anyway for me to populate by simply multiplying these 10 posts by, say, 100?

Comment: So you want to insert all the posts again 9 times?

Comment: Yep, basically... @Dogbert

Comment: That's what seeds are for

Comment: I've heard of seeds but how do you handle existing data? Could you elaborate? @Stefan

Comment: I should have been more precise. If your app needs an initial data set of 100 posts, you should create them in your `db/seeds.rb` file rather than doing it manually.

Comment: Right, I knew this but my app contains photos & I wanted to see how it act with lots of them. So I created a couple posts manually & used the 9.times do dup method as "Dogbert" listed below. But for future reference, is there a way I can do this with your way of doing it? (my seeds.rb file is empty btw) @Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.dup` for this:

```
posts = Post.all.to_a
9.times do
  posts.each do |post|
    post.dup.save
  end
end
```

`.to_a` will make sure all the records are fetched immediately, so adding new records won't cause any problems.

Comment: You know, I've been tackling hard problems with Rails all week to the point where I over complicate the simple ones. I didn't do the exact way you did it but I just simple multiplied them for the view. But still, you helped shed light on something that should've been obvious for me, so thank you :) @Dogbert